# pop array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I need to have this output

```
Array
(
   [id:>] => 0
   [isonline] => 0
   [userclass_id] => 3
)
```

and I am getting this output with this code:

```
$pr = array('id:>'=>$id,'isonline'=>'0','userclass_id'=>'3');
print_r($params);
```

This is good. But i want to pop new elements to array one by one.
While i am using this code:

```
$params = array();
array_push($params,array('userclass_id'=>'3'));  //  Members
array_push($params,array('isonline'=>'0')); // Online
array_push($params,array('id:>'=>$id));
```

I am getting this output:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [userclass_id] => 3
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [isonline] => 0
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [id:>] => 0
    )
)
```

I want to dynamically add new element but also want to have first output. Thanks for your helps.

Comment: I don't recommend the naming of 'id:>'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of key values in an associative array don't matter. Therefore you don't need to `array_push` or `array_unshift`. The only thing you need to do is associate a key to the value  you want (or vice-versa). So you would write the following to dynamically add values to the `$params` array.

```
$key = "my_id:2";
$value = "23";
$params[$key] = $value;
```

Yep, no shifting, or pushing... just add the `$key` between the square brackets and your all good.

Answer (score 1):

```
$element = array();
$element['userclass_id'] = 3;
$element['isoline'] = 0;
$element['id:>'] = $id;

$params[] = $element
```

Comment: But i don't know the key and value that i will add.

Comment: If your looking for performance, this: $params[] = $element is faster than array_push()

Comment: "But i don't know the key and value that i will add." Have you tried `$element[$key] = $value`?

Comment: "But i don't know the key and value that i will add." You can count the elements in the array, using count($array) and then add 1 to it.

So $array[(count($array) + 1)]['userclass_id'] = 3; and so on.

Comment: @Sbm007: "$array[(count($array) + 1)]['userclass_id'] = 3" never do that. use the [] operator.

Answer (score 1):

You are using array_push which adds elements to the end of the array. You should be using array_unshift, which will prepend new items to the beginning of the array.

When programatically relying on array order in php... array_pop, array_push, array_shift, and array_unshift are your friends. Know them... love them...

[php manual entry for array_unshift](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unshift.php)

Answer (score 1):

erenon's answer is probably better, but if you *really* want to add the sub-array one element at a time:

```
$params = array();
array_unshift($params,array('userclass_id'=>'3'));  //  Members
$params[0]['isonline'] = 0;                         //  Online
$params[0]['id:>'] = $id;
```

This works because array_unshift puts elements at the beginning of the array, therefore the new sub-array will **always** be element 0.

For performance reasons, you may wish to do this instead, so that the elements are not being constantly renumbered:

```
$params = array();
$params[] = array('userclass_id'=>'3');  //  Members
end($params); // Move to the new element
$key = key($params); // Get the key of the new element
$params[$key]['isonline'] = 0;           //  Online
$params[$key]['id:>'] = $id;
```

Answer (score 1):

What was happening is that you were pushing your a new array onto the current array instead of merging your new array into your old array. 
$params = array();

```
$params = array_merge($params, array('userclass_id' => 3));  //  Members
$params = array_merge($params, array('isonline'=>'0')); // Online
$params = array_merge($params, array('id:>' => $id));
```

Or even better yet you can just call array_merge once and pass it all the values

```
$params = array_merge($params, array('userclass_id' => 3), array('isonline' => '0'), array('id:>' => $id));
```

Another way to get your desired output would be just assigning the keys directly on the array.

```
$params = array();
$params['userclass_id'] = 3;
$params['isoline'] = 0;
$params['id:>'] = $id;
```

And probably the best way of doing things is just to assign the keys when the array is created.

```
$params = array(
    'userclass_id' => 3,
    'isoline' => 0,
    'id:>' => $id
);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just

```
$aParams[] = array(
    'userclass_id' => 3,
    'isoline' => 0,
    'id:>' => $id
);
```

I'm a big fan of assigning all the values in an array entry this way, vs. individual assignment statements.